# Big Cartel - Possible to immediately redirect product page to external URL?

Tags: bigcartel, external-url

first time posting :)

I'm selling art prints through my Big Cartel website and I have 4 products which are already being sold through a gallery on an external URL.

Is it possible to list specific products which immediately redirect to an external URL when clicked on instead of showing the product page on my site?

Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Jamie

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I know very little about coding and wouldn't want to waste your time by listing very basic and unsuitable fixes, I put the question to Big Cartel and they said that it's not something they can offer but to try putting the question to the community here :)